# Special characters not getting displayed correctly in html button Title

Tags: javascript, html

I know this is very basic question, but we are tumbled on to it.

We have a simple button in HTML file

```
<button data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Button" id="reset" name="reset" title="This is Reset button">Reset</button>
```

We have implemented the internationalization using dojo i18n feature and have provided appropriate French translation of the title property of the button as `R&#233;initialiser la recherche`.

The special characters in that message gets displayed correctly in French if I use that message to display the HTML label like `Réinitialiser la recherche`. But when I use the same i18n message in html button's title property, it is getting displayed as it is in the properties file `R&#233;initialiser la recherche`.

Has anyone faced this issue or know the trick to display special characters in Button's title property?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was resolved when we used `R\u00E9initialiser la recherche` instead of `R&#233;initialiser`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display special characters in a title attribute, you can just enter the character itself (use `é` not `&#233;`), you just need a character encoding. Add the following `<meta>` tag to your `<head>`:

```
<meta charset="utf-8" />
```

And then set your button's `title` attribute like so:

```
title="Réinitialiser la recherche"
```

And it should work.

Comment: It didn't help. As mentioned in the question, we are using DOJO framework and HTML file content starts with a DIV tag. If I include a <meta> tag in the beginning, the page would not load at all.